# How to find time complexity of anagram Algo

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

Preface: This is not a homework question. I'm going through an algos book in Python.

If I have the following code to solve an anagram.

```
Public bool anagram (string a, string b) {
    return sort(a) == sort(b);
}
```

Let's say the sorting algorithm is merge sort which is *O(n log n)*. Since I have to do it twice does the time complexity become *O(n^2 log n)*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, since you need to do it a constant number of times, the complexity remains `O(n log n)`.

Note that there is one more operation that you need to perform - namely, comparing strings. However, it's `O(n)`, and `O(n + n log n)` remains `O(n log n)`.

Also note that your `n` is "underdefined": you should say that `n` is `max(a.length, b.length)`

Answer (score 1):

no, it becomes `O(2*[n log n])`, but it's the same as `O(n log n)`

still, you have to compare the two sorted strings, which is linear in the length, so it becomes `O(n + n log n)`, which is again in `nlogn`